# Theme Views row with Panels in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-theming

I was wondering if it was possible to theme a Views row using panels, I know views has it's own theme settings but I wouldn't say it's a versatile as panels.

Is it possible to create a panel to handle a row outputted by a view?
Or is there a better way to theme views similar to panels?

My ultimate goal is to place some fields on the left hand side of a row and a single field on the right. This is possible with CSS but it'd be interesting to know if there is a solution to my question above.

Comment: Sounds to me like you're wanting to use a Views Content Pane to display the view but I've been up a long time so who knows.  In all honesty, Views may be more complicated (aka breaking open the .tpl.php files) but it's just as versatile, if not more so, as Panels.  But you can't go wrong either way i guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Views in Drupal 7 has a display setting for Panels. Under "Format -> Show" select "Panel Fields." "Settings" will let you select the panels layout you want, and let you position your fields into the appropriate panel positions.

Comment: You sir, Are a gent! This will really improve my workflow, thank you!